# Does hapi js uses redis to share session?

Tags: redis, hapi.js

Redis is commonly used by expressJS to share session across multiple node js processes. Does hapiJs use similar technique?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before I answer your question, I want to give a little background. Yes, you can use Redis for sharing sessions but first be sure it's what you really want/need Things are a bit different with hapi and Express when it comes to sessions.

If you've already decided this is the setup you want, skip to part 2.

### 1. Background

**In Express, the only thing stored in your cookie is your session ID.** This means when you need to scale beyond a single server, you need to look at sharing sessions between them somehow. Redis is one option.

> Note Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session ID. Session data is stored server-side.
>
> https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionoptions

The official session plugin for hapi [Yar](https://github.com/hapijs/yar), takes a slightly different approach than Express. **As long as the data that you're trying to store in a session is below `maxCookieSize`, the entire session will be encrypted (via [Iron](https://github.com/hueniverse/iron)) and stored in a cookie**. This means you don't need any extra machinery server-side to scale horizontally because the client remembers everything.

However, if this doesn't fit your requirements or you just don't like it, you can force server-side storage by setting Yar's `maxCookieSize` to `0`.

> `maxCookieSize` - maximum cookie size before using server-side storage. Defaults to 1K. Set to zero to always use server-side storage.
>
> https://github.com/hapijs/yar/blob/master/API.md

### 2. Using Redis with Yar and Server-side storage

When using Yar with server-side storage, hapi will use its [cache](http://hapijs.com/api#servercacheoptions) functionality to store your data. To use Redis for example, just pass along a Redis `cache` configuration to Yar:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Hoek = require('hoek');

const server = new Hapi.Server({
    cache: {
        engine: require('catbox-redis'),
        name: 'session',                  // cache name
        host: '127.0.0.1',                // redis host
        port: 6379,                       // redis port
        database: 'my-db'                 // redis-db
    }
});

server.register({
    register: require('yar'),
    options: {
        maxCookieSize: 0,                 // force server-side storage
        cache: {
            cache: 'session'
        },
        cookieOptions: {
            password: 'U32KuiKPnVguRKM',  // cookie password
            isSecure: false               // allow non HTTPS
        }
    }
}, (err) => {

    Hoek.assert(!err, err);
    server.start((err) => {

        Hoek.assert(!err, err);
        console.log('Started server');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very clear answer. I like the alternatives provided by hapi js. I think I will store the session data in the cookie as the data is quite small.

Comment: how can we set the value in cookies incase we want to set authtoken in cookie like req.session.authtoken